# How to reverse a keyframe animation on unchecked?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, css-selectors, css-animations

I'm attempting to develop a burger menu > minimalist arrow animation for mobile pages using *exclusively* CSS and HTML as I'm trying to get better at using CSS. I'm using keyframes to animate and a checkbox input to trigger animations. I've got the burger to turn into the arrow on click but I can't figure out how to animate it from the arrow back into the burger when the checkbox is unchecked. The HTML and CSS can be found below:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 660px;
  height: 660px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-input {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.bar {
  height: 33.333%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar-child {
  background-color: aqua;
  align-self: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 55%;
}

.burger-input:checked+.burger-label .bar-child {
  transition: border-radius 0.4s ease-in-out 0.4s;
  border-radius: 250px;
}

.burger-input:checked+.burger-label .bar:nth-child(1) {
  align-self: end;
  animation: width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards, centerBurger 0.4s linear 0.4s 1 normal forwards;
}

.burger-input:checked+.burger-label .bar:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: start;
  animation: width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards, leftArrowHead 0.4s ease-in-out 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
}

.burger-input:checked+.burger-label .bar:nth-child(3) {
  align-self: end;
  animation: width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards, moveBurgerUp 0.4s linear 0.4s 1 normal forwards, rightArrowHead 0.4s ease-in-out 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes leftArrowHead {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-46%) rotate(-50deg);
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@keyframes rightArrowHead {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-146%) rotate(50deg);
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@keyframes moveBurgerUp {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes centerBurger {
  from {}
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-330px + 50%));
  }
}

@keyframes width20 {
  from {
    width: 90%;
  }
  to {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="burger-btn-body">
  <input type="checkbox" class="burger-input" id="burger-input">
  <label for="burger-input" class="burger-label">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="bar-child" id="bar-child1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="bar-child" id="bar-child2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="bar-child" id="bar-child3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

I'm willing to swap to SCSS if necessary but I'd really like to not use any JavaScript code as I feel it would defeat the purpose of this exercise for me. I believe this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27710302/19717218) may have solved my problem with it using SCSS but is this possible in pure CSS?

I've tried just applying a standard reverse on the animations as they were

```css
.burger-input:not(:checked) + .burger-label .bar:nth-child(2) {
     align-self: start;     
     animation: 
     width20 0.4s ease-in 0.8s 1 normal reverse,
     leftArrowHead 0.4s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal reverse;   
}
```

I've also tried using transitions on unchecked as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619594/19717218)

```css
.burger-input:not(:checked) + .burger-label .bar:nth-child(1) {
     align-self: end;
     transition: transform 0.4s linear 0s;     
     transform: translateX(calc(330px - 50%));   
}
```

I've also tried new custom animations for the reverse mode

```css
.burger-input:not(:checked) + .burger-label .bar:nth-child(1) {
    align-self: end;
    animation:
    width20 0.4s ease-in 0.4s 1 normal reverse,
    centerBurgerReverse 0.4s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes centerBurgerReverse {
    from{

    }
    to{
      transform: translateX(calc(330px - 50%));
    }

}
```

Comment: That is not valid HTML. `Permitted content for <label>: Phrasing content, but no descendant label elements. No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed.`

Comment: _"I believe this comment may have solved my problem with it using SCSS but is this possible in pure CSS?"_ - browsers do not interpret SCSS directly, it gets _compiled into_ CSS first. So of course you can do _anything_ you can do with SCSS, with directly written "static" CSS as well.

Comment: _"but I'd really like to not use any JavaScript code as I feel it would defeat the purpose of this exercise for me"_ - this may be fine for a theoretical exercise, but it is rather not a thing for productive use in the first place. Part of "getting better at using CSS" should also be to develop the ability to judge, in what situations this might _not_ be the appropriate solution. And such "pure CSS solutions" for stuff like this, often have usability drawbacks, especially for users using assistive technology.

Comment: i understand what you tried and why but this approach is very rough. You can basically achieve something like that with CSS Transitions and a lot of workarounds to avoid JavaScript. I would not recommend that though since it wont help you out for "real" or rather "usable" applications. You might learn a thing or two about the capabilities of "pure CSS" but this has no real use-case scenario. I would put that energy into learning how to get the most efficient working solution with maybe minimal JS.

Comment: To answer Warden330, I understand your point of view and you're right in that this has little use case in most real applications. However, the application I'm using can't use JavaScript (it can but in a limited capacity and will leave it open to vulnerabilities I'd rather just avoid by sanitizing the HTML ).

Comment: CBroe thank you for your answer. I have little experience with SCSS so knowing it compiles to CSS is very helpful to me. As for your second comment, I'm not a web developer. I'm a hobbyist who enjoys writing CSS. I have an application I need to use this for that has sanitized HTML involved, meaning no JavaScript. I was hoping to get a pure CSS solution as I don't know if it can use SCSS with it but I should be able to decompile an SCSS solution to get the pure CSS solution I'm looking for. Thank you.

Comment: mplungjan thank for your input on my HTML. I got the idea from another solution. It's as follows ```<div class="burger-btn-body">
     <input type="checkbox" class="burger-input" id="burger-input">
    <label for="burger-input" class="burger-label">
        <span class="burger-line"></span>
    </label>
    </div>``` Could you maybe expand on how to improve my HTML?

Comment: In future you may find it helpful to put your code through a validator e.g. https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the timing used on the animation CSS property.

```
.burger-input:not(:checked) + .burger-label .bar:nth-child(1) {
    align-self: end;
    animation:
    width20 0.4s ease-in 0.4s 1 normal reverse,
    centerBurgerReverse 0.4s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

The above code doesn't work because the delay for width20 is longer than the delay on centerBurgerReverse. The code should be:

```
.burger-input:not(:checked) + .burger-label .bar:nth-child(1) {
    align-self: end;
    animation:
    centerBurgerReverse 0.4s linear 0s 1 normal forwards,
    width20 0.4s ease-in 0.4s 1 normal reverse;
}
```

The full code (in SCSS as it was pointed out that it compiles to CSS anyway) is as follows:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 660px;
    height: 660px;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .burger-input{
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
  }

  .bar{
    height: 33.333%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .bar-child{
    background-color: aqua;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
  }

  .burger-input{
    &:not(:checked) + .burger-label {
      & .bar-child{
        transition: border-radius 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
        border-radius: 25px;
      }
      & .bar{
        &:nth-child(1) {
          align-self: end;
          animation: 
          width20Reverse 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards,centerBurgerReverse 0.4s linear 0s 1 normal forwards;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          align-self: start;
          animation: 
          leftArrowHeadReverse 0.4s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards,width20Reverse 0.4s ease-in 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
          align-self: end;
          animation: 
          rightArrowHeadReverse 0.4s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal forwards, moveBurgerUpReverse 0.4s linear 0.4s 1 normal forwards, width20Reverse 0.4s ease-in 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
        }
      }
    }

    &:checked + .burger-label {
      & .bar-child{
        transition: border-radius 0.4s ease-in-out 0.4s;
        border-radius: 250px;
      }
      & .bar{
        &:nth-child(1) {
          align-self: end;
          animation: 
            width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards,centerBurger 0.4s linear 0.4s 1 normal forwards;
        }
        &:nth-child(2) {
          align-self: start;
          animation: 
            width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards,leftArrowHead 0.4s ease-in-out 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
          align-self: end;
          animation: 
            width20 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards,moveBurgerUp 0.4s linear 0.4s 1 normal forwards,rightArrowHead 0.4s ease-in-out 0.8s 1 normal forwards;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @keyframes leftArrowHead {
    0%{
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(-46%) rotate(-50deg);
      width: 68%;
    }
  }

  @keyframes rightArrowHead {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(30deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(-146%) rotate(50deg);
      width: 68%;
    }
  }

  @keyframes moveBurgerUp {
    from{

    }
    to{
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
  }

  @keyframes centerBurger {
    from{

    }
    to{
      transform: translateX(calc(-330px + 50%));
    }
  }

  @keyframes width20 {
    from {
      width: 90%;
    }
    to {
      width: 20%;
    }
  }

  /* Reverse animations when unchecked */
  @keyframes leftArrowHeadReverse {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(-46%) rotate(-50deg);
      width: 70%;
    }
    100%{
      transform: rotate(0deg);
      width: 20%;
    }
  }

  @keyframes rightArrowHeadReverse {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(-146%) rotate(50deg);
      width: 70%;
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(0deg);
      width: 20%;
    }
  }

  @keyframes moveBurgerUpReverse {
    from{
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    to{
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
  }

  @keyframes centerBurgerReverse {
    from{
      transform: translateX(calc(-330px + 50%));
    }
    to{
      transform: translateX(calc(330px - 50%));
    }
  }

  @keyframes width20Reverse {
    from {
      width: 20%;
    }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

This code is messy but can be neatened up as needed